# How would I make this go back to the previous question instead of infinitely repeating

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I've been trying to get this to work, so I have a program that at this point is supposed to ask if you make programs a lot, but it keeps looping on a part of it I think due to a function that I've made, but I plan to use this function a lot, so it would be best if I don't have to remove it.

I have tried putting it into a `while` loop as suggested by other people on here, but I think I may have done it incorrectly, I was expecting it to go back to the "do you make a lot of programs?" question after the function `huh()` has `washappening` as `True`, but instead `huh()` just repeats itself. Here is the code (not all of it, just the part where the problem happens):

```
def huh(): 
    washappening = False  
    while not washappening:


        typo= input("""i dont understand? Did you make a typo??""")
        if typo == "yes" or typo == "Yes":
            print ("oh, no worries ill just ask the question again")
            washappening = True
        elif typo == "no" or typo == "No":
            print("o....k.... I still dont understand so try the question again")
            washappening = True
        else:
            print("""aaaaand even more words i dont understand... i should look at a dictionary.
            anyways try the question again but maybe with a simpler question?""")
            washappening = True





def open_question():
       
    
    if language=="python" or language=="Python":
        print("SAME! its quite easy so i like it quite a lot, would be even more "+random.choice(goodwords)+"if (cant think of anything)")

        pyq1= input("do you make a lot of programs? ")

        valid = False
        while not valid:
            if pyq1 == "yes" or pyq1 == "Yes":
                print("wow, we're very alike")
                valid = True
            elif pyq1 == "no" or pyq1 == "No":
                print("understandable, programming can take some time" )
                valid =  True     
            elif pyq1 == "A bit" or pyq1 =="A little" or pyq1 =="A little bit" or pyq1 =="Kinda" or pyq1 =="a bit" or pyq1 =="a little" or pyq1 =="a litle bit " or pyq1 =="kinda":
                print("understandable, programming can take some time")
                valid = True
            else:
                huh()
```

Comment: `input("do you make a log of programs")` is not part of a loop, so it won't go back there ever again. So, to go back there, make it part of a loop (like you already did for other parts of your program).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the *while* loop in the "huh" function.
Try removing the while loop completely, and when any of the conditions are met, just say:

```
return
```

instead of:

```
washappening = True
```

And then in the *open_question* function, after you call the *huh* fuction, say:

```
open_question()
```

to re-ask the original question.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer. I'm excited!

Ok so, the `huh()` function is never changing `valid` value to true, so the while loops continues infinitely

The `do you make a lot of programs?` input is outside the while loop, so it's never going to ask that again